# Elastic Search Deduplication

Tags: elasticsearch

Working on Elastic Search 6.5.x. I indexed the documents into ES index via external web crawler. Below is my Index. I want to get the records based on the filter. If I use the below query, Suppose if I use term query by **https** the http results are not displaying same for the **http**. Records 1 and 2 looks like similar but the difference is https and http in the URL. How can I compare records of an URL field after the protocol. If it has same info how can I display either one of the record with remaining unique records.

**Index:**

```
"title": "About elastic search"
"content": "Elasticsearch is an open source distributed, RESTful search and analytics engine capable of solving a growing number of use cases."
"URL: "https://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-elasticsearch"`

"title":"About elastic search"
"content":"Elasticsearch is an open source distributed, RESTful search and analytics engine capable of solving a growing number of use cases."
"URL":"http://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-elasticsearch"

"title":"About Similarity"
"content":"A similarity (scoring / ranking model) defines how matching documents are scored. Similarity is per field, meaning that via the mapping one can define a different similarity per field."
"URL":"https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/index-modules-similarity.html"

"title":"SQL Access"
"content":"This functionality is experimental and may be changed or removed completely in a future release. Elastic will take a best effort approach to fix any issues, but experimental features are not subject to the support SLA of official GA features."
"URL":"http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-sql.html"
```

**Query:**

```
GET test-index/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "query_string":{
               "query":"test"
            }
         },
         "filter": {  
             "bool" : {
                 "must" : 
                    {"term" : { "url" : "https" } }
               }}
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve can only be partially achieved via query. It should be handled while indexing. For e.g. while indexing remove the protocol info and index only remaining url info.

Comment: Protocol info cannot be remove. I am indexing from a web crawler.

Comment: I don't think that the output of web crawler which is directly being indexed to elastic right now, can't be modified by a layer in between both.

Comment: I tried to remove the protocol headers in the crawler  and applying the Deduplication but It will not worked.